# Is Approximate Number System used only for comparing magnitudes of groups of things, or does it also help in actual counting?

Tags: brain-development, mathematical-ability, numerical-cognition

By ANS I am referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_number_system)

According to [this reddit answer](https://np.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2ayhkp/if_someone_asks_me_how_many_apples_are_on_the/cj02b7r/)

> The human mind has two systems for representing numbers: a subitizing
>   system for numbers up to four, and an approximate ratio estimation
>   system for larger numbers.

It means that if we don't know how to count, we can only know about numbers upto 4. Anything more than that and we activate ANS system.

But ANS system can't be useful for counting right? It is useful only when we have two groups of things. It is not useful when we want to estimate a magnitude of a single group of things. Is that correct?

Comment: The ANS does not give an absolute and accurate number, but it provides a useful estimation of the quantity, the same way we estimate and characterize a fish as small or big. So we may see an apple tree and estimate that it has few apples or many apples. ANS is though susceptible to the [contrast effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_effect), like any intuitive measure we make.